# Embedding RDP webpage in WordPress

Tags: vb.net, wordpress, rdp

So my dad wants to be able to RDP from a webpage. He knows this is a Windows Only thing anyway, but the problem is that I can't embed it in WP. Works fine standalone, but as soon as I embed it in a template or iFrame it, it stops working.

Any ideas?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380809(v=vs.85).aspx works if I put that on it's own webpage, but as soon as I put it in WP, it dies. I know jack about VB so any suggestions for someone who is great at WP, but poor at Windows/IIS/VB is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty good at all of the tech you mentioned.
WP is not special, after all of the server side processing it emits standard web stuff.

I can offer some standard debugging tips to see what the problem is:

- Is it an HTTP/HTTPS issue?
- Is it an CrossFrame/XSS issue?
- Did you see any errors being thrown in the browser's console?
- Did you run fiddler on it and see if there are any errors?
- Did you look at the IIS logs to see if there were any errors?

Comment: Not http/https (all http). The only way to make it work at all is on a Windows interface, which limits me since ... well, I use a Mac. On a lark, I tried it with compatibility mode on, and that worked... so damn it.

Comment: Sorry about the double post, apparently I can't hit enter? Okay. Testing on IE 9

* F12 Dev console says: `SCRIPY5009: 'BtnConnect' is undefined` (this does not occur in compat mode). 
* Putting in the compat meta does not work.
* Does not appear to be xss (the iframe is in the main HTML folder too, FWIW).
* Error logs for IIS are clean.